# List comprehension of numpy arrays in eclipse generates NameError

Tags: python, eclipse, numpy

I tested some code in Eclipse Console, in debug mode. 
(Eclipse version is Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a)):

```
import numpy as np

r = np.random.randn(1000,3)

[r[0,0]]

[-1.5771689441146768]

i=0; np.arange(np.floor(np.min(r[:,i])), np.ceil(np.max(r[:,i]))+1)

array([-4., -3., -2., -1.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.])

[i for i in range(3)]

[0, 1, 2]


bins = [np.arange(np.floor(np.min(r[:,i])), np.ceil(np.max(r[:,i]))+1) for i in range(3)]
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users...\org.python.pydev_5.8.0.201706061859\pysrc_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_exec2.py", line 3, in Exec
>       exec(exp, global_vars, local_vars)
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "", line 1, in 
>   NameError: name 'r' is not defined

Why use of r causes NameError in list comprehension?
Alone, list comprehension works and array creation works too. 
I'm confused...

Tested same in Python 3.6 shell, and no error. 
In Eclipse, my Python Interpreter is also 3.6.

EDIT: It must be related to Eclipse debug mode, I tested code in debug run and this worked:

> r = np.random.randn(1000,3)
>   bins = [np.arange(np.floor(np.min(r[:,i])), np.ceil(np.max(r[:,i]))+1) for i in range(3)]
>   print(bins)

Comment: I test your code in my envirment(Python 3.5.2),there is no error.

Comment: Yes, it is linked to Eclipse console in its debug mode, ie. not a serious problem, but first time I noticed this kind of "false error"

Comment: I meant it occurs when typing commands in Eclipse console, not in normal debug run.

Comment: Is this related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45721532/pydev-in-debug-mode-nameerror-dict-pop-when-importing-pandas-or-xarray

Comment: Perhaps... but as far as I can understand there was the problem in debug run. In this case, weird things happen, when I use console commands during debug run (if it is in the code that I'm debugging with F6, there will be no errors). I'm just curious if the error I found can be repeated in other Eclipse-Python combinations?